# P&T Contact Form not submitting Craft 2

Tags: error, plugin-contactform

I'm working on a site that I did not build.

The first party contact form stopped submitting so I updated Craft and all plugins. All went smoothly but the form is still not  submitting.

Checked the templates and compared to the docs and it appears that it should work (was previously). Any recommendations on how to better troubleshoot?

```
<div class="form-container">
  {% from _self import errorList %}

  <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {{ getCsrfInput() }}
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contactForm/sendMessage">
      <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/careers/apply-now#form-thanks">

      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="fromName">Name</label>
        <input id="fromName" type="text" name="message[fromName]" placeholder="Your Name" value="">
        {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromName')) }}
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-element">
        <label for="fromEmail">Email</label>
        <input id="fromEmail" type="text" name="fromEmail" placeholder="Your Email" value="">
        {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromEmail')) }}
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone</label>
        <input id="phoneNumber" type="text" name="message[phoneNumber]" placeholder="Your Phone Number" value="">
        {{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('phoneNumber')) }}
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-element">
      <label for="position">Position</label>
      <input id="position" type="text" name="message[position]" placeholder="Position of Interest" value="" />
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-element">
      <label class="button" for="attachment">Attach Resume</label>
      <input type="file" id="attachment" name="attachment" />
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Career Form Submission" />
    <input type="hidden" name="nothanks" id="nothanks" value="" />

    <div class="form-element submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Define "stopped submitting". Does it still _appear_ to submit?

Comment: @LindseyD Yes it appears to submit, but nothing is received. I added myself to the reciever list, checked spam and haven't received any email after submitting and the form takes you to the thank you page after submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with your **email configuration**, not the form plugin.

Check your site wide email settings, specifically check the "Protocol". If you are using "PHP Mail", you're gonna have a lot of problems. The best option is "SMTP".

[image: Protocol dropdown menu]

There are several SMTP services to choose from. We've been using Mailgun for several years, and are very happy with them.

Comment: Also worth linking to: https://craftcms.com/support/troubleshooting-email-errors#dealing-with-email-delivery-issues

Comment: Yes it's using php mail. I didn't even think of that. Thanks Lindsey. Will talk to client now.